# How do I make my bot respond to a user mention without on_message event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

> Blockquote

```
@client.command()
async def afk(ctx, activity=None):
    if ctx.author.mention:
        await ctx.send(f"""{ctx.author.mention} is currently afk. Reason: {activity}""")

    else:
        print("A user is afk...")
```

I'm trying to make an afk command and this is all I got. I'm having trouble making my bot respond to a user who has just recently used this afk command. Basically I'm trying to make Dyno bot's afk command.

```
"The AFK module allows users to set an AFK status inside of your server. If a user sets an AFK status, Dyno will leave a message displaying their AFK status whenever the user is mentioned. Dyno will automatically add “[AFK]” to the beginning of your nickname whenever you set an AFK status (if it has the permissions to)."
```

This is the definition of Dyno's afk command. That is basically what I'm trying to do as well.

Comment: Maybe the post got downvoted because you don't mention what block or error you have? What is the outcome of this piece of code and what did you expect? When does this run and what have you tried for yourself? Did debugging fail or did you not yet try that? You currently left it up to us to guess all this.

Comment: I've explained a bit more, sorry for the inconvenience and lack of explanation

Comment: This might sound blunt (and sorry for that) but it looks like your trying to replicate a program without knowing what to do. This is not a specific question or bug you encounter but rather a "guide me trhough the steps to replicate X". I think you might want to rethink your strategy (maybe first check python tutorials, read the discord.py documentation if available, thinks like that). If you then encounter something you can't solve at least the community have something to work from.

Comment: All right. All I'm asking for is how to make my bot respond to a specific user mention without an on_message event. This is all I want. I have researched and I have not found anything on it. I have read the documentation but I don't understand it. I'm extremely new to python, so things are still a bit unclear to me. ALL I'M asking for is, how can I make my bot respond to a specific user's mention.

Comment: Aha but this makes more sense now. You just mentioned in your comment "how to make my bot respond to a specific user mention without an on_message event". This would be a fine question to ask all by itself for it is a narrowed down question. I would suggest adding this to your original question and see if anyone can answer that. Might result in more input than just stating "basically I want to replicate this program".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to copy other creators without having the knowledge of the actual library. You need to use your own logic and understand the concepts.

I don't how know dyno works, However, I have understood what actually you are trying to say and this snippet can give you an idea of how things work and how you can implement them in your code.

```
#STORING THE USER IN A LIST
afk_list = []
@bot.command()
async def afk(ctx):
    global afk_list
    # IF USER ID IS NOT FOUND IN THE LIST
    if not ctx.author.id in afk_list:
        #STORE THE ID IN THE LIST
        afk_list.append(ctx.author.id)
        #EDIT THE NAME OF THE AUTHOR
        await ctx.author.edit(nick = f'[AFK] {ctx.author.name}')
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You have been marked as AFK.')
        return afk_list
    else:
        afk_list.remove(ctx.author.id)
        nick = ctx.author.name.replace('[AFK]','')
        await ctx.author.edit(nick = nick)
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} You are no longer AFK.')
        return afk_list

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global afk_list
    try:
        #We check if the message starts with any mentionable content
        if message.content.startswith('<'):
            a = message.content
            a = a.replace('<','')
            a = a.replace('@','')
            a = a.replace('!','')
            a = a.replace('>','')
            a = int(a)
            #HERE We have replaced all the strings and converted it into Integar.
            if a in afk_list:
                #If the User in the LIST, The message will be sent.
                user = bot.get_user(a)
                await message.channel.send(f'{user.name} is currently AFK')
            else:
                pass
    except Exception:
        pass
        
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Well, this is basically my way of learning. I get answers, I study the answers and try to redo it my own. Or rather just apply the concept I just picked up from that answer. Not trying to copy because my bot isn't even official XD. Just a bot I use in my friends's server. :>

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it's all right. I'll try to code it myself in the future. Besides that, yes, it's a great help. YOU'VE been a great help. Thanks Sofia :)